# 4 answers deleted by moderator is there a sense to continue?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-questions, moderation

This is the question about moderation. I have recently answered 4 question about AWS deployments and the answers was deleted by a moderator. I was trying to answer the question and make the answer useful. I also promoted my new service but honestly stated that I am affiliated with it. Is there any broken rules regarding this? Is there a sense to continue? My understanding that my actions not differ to any other commercial service including AWS. So, why one companies can be listed in the answers and another can't?
Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `"I also promote my new service..."` -- I don't need to read any more. No there's no sense to continue if you do this. Whether you agree or not, this constitutes spam and has no business on StackOverflow.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I do agree. But my product solves the specific problem. So, I do believe it is a solution. What's wrong with this?

Comment: You are not an un-biased volunteer helping someone else out out of purely altruistic motives.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Hmm... companies support are not altruistic as well. And consultants who wish to promote themselves as a consultants are not altruistic. Is there any rules about altruism?

Comment: Please don't create any artificial straw men -- we're not talking about company support or consultants  -- we're only talking about what constitutes allowed content on stackoverflow, and for that there **are** rules about spam and self-promotion.

Comment: It's pretty simple really: Don't answer shopping/recommendation questions. And if you find they are still open, help us close them. Other than that there are various posts on here as well as on http://meta.stackexchange.com regarding the limits of self-promotion.

Comment: Ok. Your position is clear. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 15):

All four of your answers were advertising your company/product and on [shopping questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Yes, you did declare your affiliation, but you shouldn't have been answering those type of question in the first place and the answers were flagged as spam.

Had the moderator not deleted the answers there's a good chance they would have been deleted by the community flagging as spam which would have earned you a 100 point reduction in reputation **per answer**.

Comment: Well, as I said, the answer had provide a solution to the question. If shopping questions are so unproductive, why SO still allows it? I do believe that the answers would not be flagged as it are helpful.

Comment: @PavelKorsukov - we don't allow shopping questions. There's a specific close reason for them and if you notice, all four question have now been closed.

Comment: You might find this helpful, @Pavel: http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion